# How put pixel by click on ImageView in Android

Tags: android, click, imageview, listener

How can I write listener and what this listener must be (OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, ...) for change color of the ImageView pixel in point of click (touch)? Can you show me some short example of code?

Comment: Maybe some code example?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout android sample [FingerPaint](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html).